# render data with rest framework based on user input (Django)

Tags: django

I am struggling to modify this view so that a chart is generated based on user input. The underlying isssue is that I cannot find a way to make this with Django rest framework. In more details I want to return a scatter plot that takes the user input as parameter as well as data pulled from the database based on this input

Here is what I have been able to do so far:

view.py:

```
class forecast(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = request.GET.get('search_res', None)

        if query and request.method == 'GET':
            reference = Item.objects.filter(reference = query)

            forecast1 = Item.objects.filter(reference = query).values('demand_30_jours')
            forecast2 = Item.objects.filter(reference=query).values('Lt2')
            forecast3 = Item.objects.filter(reference=query).values('Lt3')

            data = {'reference': reference, 'forecastdata':[forecast1, forecast2, forecast3]}

            return Response(data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='HomeView'),
    path('items.html', ItemPage.as_view()),
    path('charts',TemplateView.as_view()),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/chart/data',ChartData.as_view()),
    path('api/chart/forecast',forecast.as_view())
```

items.html

```
 <form id="searchform"  method="get" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">
                        Search
                     <input id="searchbox" name="search_res" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                    <input type="submit" value="OK">
                </form>

  <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-header"><i class="fas fa-chart-bar mr-1"></i>90 DAYS FORWARD FORECAST</div>
                                    <div class="card-body"><canvas id="myChart" width="150" height="116"></canvas></div>
                                    <div class="card-footer small text-muted">References</div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var endpoint = '/api/chart/forecast'
                var forecastdata= []
                var reference = []

                ;

                $.ajax({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: endpoint,
                        success: function (data) {
                   data: {'search_res' : $('search_res').val(),},



                            reference = data.reference
                            forecastdata = data.forecastdata


                            setChart()
                        },
                        error: function (error_data) {

                            console.log(error_data)
                        }
                    }
                )

                function setChart(){
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

                    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'scatter',
                        data: {
                            labels: reference,
                            datasets: [{
                                label: 'inventory classes',
                                data: forecastdata,
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                                ],
                                borderWidth: 1
                            }],
                            options: {
                                scales: {
                                    yAxes: [{
                                        gridLines: {
                                            display: true,
                                            drawOnChartArea: false,
                                        },
                                        ticks: {
                                            beginAtZero: true
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
 }
}
)
</script>
```

and I get the error in '/api/chart/forecast':

```
AssertionError at /api/chart/forecast
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

model.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    fournisseur = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    demand_30_jours = models.FloatField(default=0)
    lt2 = models.FloatField(default=0)
    lt3 = models.FloatField(default=0)
    error_forecast = models.FloatField(default=0)
    stock_reel = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    en_cours_de_reception = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    delai_fournisseur = models.FloatField(default=0)
    cout_dimport = models.FloatField(default=0)
    cout_de_stockage = models.FloatField(default=0)
    demande_durant_delai_fournisseur = models.FloatField(default=0)
    estimation_jours_de_stock_desiree = models.FloatField(default=0)
    stock_alerte_optimal = models.FloatField(default=0)
    candidat_reapprovisionnement = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    objectif_niveau_stock_alerte = models.FloatField(default=0)
    niveau_objectif = models.FloatField(default=0)
    quantite_a_commander = models.FloatField(default=0)
    stock_alerte_implicite = models.FloatField(default=0)
    niveau_service_implicite = models.FloatField(default=0)
    niveau_service_optimal = models.FloatField(default=0)
    estimation_cout_de_rupture = models.FloatField(default=0)
    prix_dachat = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reference
```

update: After more research on Ajax documentation, I have modified my html script (attached), getting now 0 error. However, the plot is still not rendering because api/chart/forecast shows '{}'. I am stuck there, I am assuming there is something wrong with my view and I am calling my data poorly so I attached the model I want to acccess. I am out of solution, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happen when your if is not satisfied? your view return none in that situation

Comment: As far as I can see, your ajax request isn't sending `search_res` as query parameter, so your view returns nothing (`None`). Your view must always return something, even if you don't expect that case. so add `else: return Response({'error': 'I did not expect this'}, status=401)`

Comment: it should not that's what I dont understand

Comment: @dirkgroten oh, good point, but how can I include it
? would it be a new var?

Comment: Look at the jquery documentation for `$.ajax`. You need to pass it as `data`.